# Erro formulario login (front)

Tags: javascript, html, css, formulário, front-end

estou fazendo uma tela de login e cadastro, mas o que era pra ser 2 em 1 acaba separando, fica o formulario de sign up em baixo do login.

Html

```
<div class="login-box">
  <div class="lb-header">
    <a href="#" class="active" id="login-box-link">Login</a>
  <a href="#" id="signup-box-link">Sign Up</a>
</div>
<div class="social-login">
  <a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-lg"></i>
    Login in with facebook
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-lg"></i>
    log in with Google
  </a>
</div>
<form class="email-login">
  <div class="u-form-group">
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email"/>
  </div>
  <div class="u-form-group">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
  </div>
  <div class="u-form-group">
    <button>Log in</button>
  </div>
  <div class="u-form-group">
    <a href="#" class="forgot-password">Forgot password?</a>
  </div>
</form>
<form class="email-signup">
  <div class="u-form-group">
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email"/>
  </div>
  <div class="u-form-group">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
  </div>
  <div class="u-form-group">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password"/>
  </div>
  <div class="u-form-group">
    <button>Sign Up</button>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
```

o css

```
body{
            background-color: #1cbb9b;
          }
          .login-box{
            position:relative;
            margin: 10px auto;
            width: 500px;
            height: 380px;
            background-color: #fff;
            padding: 10px;
            border-radius: 3px;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.33);
          -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.33);
          box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.33);
          }
          .lb-header{
            position:relative;
            color: #00415d;
            margin: 5px 5px 10px 5px;
            padding-bottom:10px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
            text-align:center;
            height:28px;
          }
          .lb-header a{
            margin: 0 25px;
            padding: 0 20px;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #666;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 15px;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.1s linear;
            -moz-transition: all 0.1s linear;
            transition: all 0.1s linear;
          }
          .lb-header .active{
            color: #029f5b;
            font-size: 18px;
          }
          .social-login{
            position:relative;
            float: left;
            width: 100%;
            height:auto;
            padding: 10px 0 15px 0;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
          }
          .social-login a{
            position:relative;
            float: left;
            width:calc(40% - 8px);
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #fff;
            border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
            padding: 12px;
            border-radius: 2px;
            font-size: 12px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            margin: 0 3%;
            text-align:center;
          }
          .social-login a i{
            position: relative;
            float: left;
            width: 20px;
            top: 2px;
          }
          .social-login a:first-child{
            background-color: #49639F;
          }
          .social-login a:last-child{
            background-color: #DF4A32;
          }
          .email-login,.email-signup{
            position:relative;
            float: left;
            width: 100%;
            height:auto;
            margin-top: 20px;
            text-align:center;
          }
          .u-form-group{
            width:100%;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
          }
          .u-form-group input[type="email"],
          .u-form-group input[type="password"]{
            width: calc(50% - 22px);
            height:45px;
            outline: none;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            padding: 0 10px;
            border-radius: 2px;
            color: #333;
            font-size:0.8rem;
            -webkit-transition:all 0.1s linear;
            -moz-transition:all 0.1s linear;
            transition:all 0.1s linear;
          }
          .u-form-group input:focus{
            border-color: #358efb;
          }
          .u-form-group button{
            width:50%;
            background-color: #1CB94E;
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: normal;
            padding: 14px 0;
            border-radius: 2px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
          }
          .forgot-password{
            width:50%;
            text-align: left;
            text-decoration: underline;
            color: #888;
            font-size: 0.75rem;
          }
```

E ADICIONEI ESSE JS

```
$(".email-signup").hide();
$("#signup-box-link").click(function(){
  $(".email-login").fadeOut(100);
  $(".email-signup").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
  $("#login-box-link").removeClass("active");
  $("#signup-box-link").addClass("active");
});
$("#login-box-link").click(function(){
  $(".email-login").delay(100).fadeIn(100);;
  $(".email-signup").fadeOut(100);
  $("#login-box-link").addClass("active");
  $("#signup-box-link").removeClass("active");
});
```

eu adicionei a query, não sei o que pode ser, quem puder ajudar

Answer (score 1):

Em vez de esconder o segundo formulário com `$(".email-signup").hide();` seria muito melhor e mais coerente esconder no próprio CSS:

```
.email-signup{
   display: none;
}
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
//$(".email-signup").hide();
$("#signup-box-link").click(function(){
  $(".email-login").fadeOut(100);
  $(".email-signup").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
  $("#login-box-link").removeClass("active");
  $("#signup-box-link").addClass("active");
});
$("#login-box-link").click(function(){
  $(".email-login").delay(100).fadeIn(100);;
  $(".email-signup").fadeOut(100);
  $("#login-box-link").addClass("active");
  $("#signup-box-link").removeClass("active");
});
```

```css
body{
   background-color: #1cbb9b;
 }
 .login-box{
   position:relative;
   margin: 10px auto;
   width: 500px;
   height: 380px;
   background-color: #fff;
   padding: 10px;
   border-radius: 3px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.33);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.33);
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.33);
 }
 .lb-header{
   position:relative;
   color: #00415d;
   margin: 5px 5px 10px 5px;
   padding-bottom:10px;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
   text-align:center;
   height:28px;
 }
 .lb-header a{
   margin: 0 25px;
   padding: 0 20px;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #666;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 15px;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.1s linear;
   -moz-transition: all 0.1s linear;
   transition: all 0.1s linear;
 }
 .lb-header .active{
   color: #029f5b;
   font-size: 18px;
 }
 .social-login{
   position:relative;
   float: left;
   width: 100%;
   height:auto;
   padding: 10px 0 15px 0;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
 }
 .social-login a{
   position:relative;
   float: left;
   width:calc(40% - 8px);
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #fff;
   border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
   padding: 12px;
   border-radius: 2px;
   font-size: 12px;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   margin: 0 3%;
   text-align:center;
 }
 .social-login a i{
   position: relative;
   float: left;
   width: 20px;
   top: 2px;
 }
 .social-login a:first-child{
   background-color: #49639F;
 }
 .social-login a:last-child{
   background-color: #DF4A32;
 }
 .email-login,.email-signup{
   position:relative;
   float: left;
   width: 100%;
   height:auto;
   margin-top: 20px;
   text-align:center;
 }
 .u-form-group{
   width:100%;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
 }
 .u-form-group input[type="email"],
 .u-form-group input[type="password"]{
   width: calc(50% - 22px);
   height:45px;
   outline: none;
   border: 1px solid #ddd;
   padding: 0 10px;
   border-radius: 2px;
   color: #333;
   font-size:0.8rem;
   -webkit-transition:all 0.1s linear;
   -moz-transition:all 0.1s linear;
   transition:all 0.1s linear;
 }
 .u-form-group input:focus{
   border-color: #358efb;
 }
 .u-form-group button{
   width:50%;
   background-color: #1CB94E;
   border: none;
   outline: none;
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 14px;
   font-weight: normal;
   padding: 14px 0;
   border-radius: 2px;
   text-transform: uppercase;
 }
 .forgot-password{
   width:50%;
   text-align: left;
   text-decoration: underline;
   color: #888;
   font-size: 0.75rem;
 }
          
.email-signup{
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="login-box">
  <div class="lb-header">
    <a href="#" class="active" id="login-box-link">Login</a>
  <a href="#" id="signup-box-link">Sign Up</a>
</div>
<div class="social-login">
  <a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-lg"></i>
    Login in with facebook
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-lg"></i>
    log in with Google
  </a>
</div>
<form class="email-login">
  <div class="u-form-group">
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email"/>
  </div>
  <div class="u-form-group">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
  </div>
  <div class="u-form-group">
    <button>Log in</button>
  </div>
  <div class="u-form-group">
    <a href="#" class="forgot-password">Forgot password?</a>
  </div>
</form>
<form class="email-signup">
  <div class="u-form-group">
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email"/>
  </div>
  <div class="u-form-group">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
  </div>
  <div class="u-form-group">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password"/>
  </div>
  <div class="u-form-group">
    <button>Sign Up</button>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
```